# Class composition and construction order?

Tags: c++, constructor, composition

I have two classes, Time and Date, and Date is composed with a Time object.  I'm having an issue with the time object.  The test program (which I am not allowed to alter) creates a time object, then it creates a Date object and passes the time object as an argument.  When the first time object is created, it initializes correctly, but when the Date object constructor is called, it doesn't use the arguments from the original time object.  Instead it creates a new Time object and uses my default argument of (0,0,0), which was required to be included in my Time constructor and Time class definition.

What I want to do is instead pass the arguments supplied to the Time object to the Date constructor's Time argument, so that the Time constructor does not use the default (0,0,0) argument.  I tried using references to the time object but I can't get it to work.

Here's my two class headers and the test code.  Note that the test code is not allowed to be altered.  I thought of just adding the arguments to the date object when it is created, but that code is not allowed to be altered.

Test code:

```
#include <iostream> 
using std::cout; 
using std::endl; 

#include "Time.h" // include Time class definition
#include "Date.h" // include Date class definition

const int MAX_TICKS = 20;

int main()
{
   Time t(23, 59, 58);// create a time object
   Date d(12, 31, 2014, t); // create date object

   // output Time object t's values 
   for ( int ticks = 1; ticks < MAX_TICKS; ++ticks ) 
   {
      d.print(); // invokes print 
      cout << endl;
      d.tick(); // invokes function tick
   } // end for
   d.~Date();// call Date destructor
   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
} // end main
```

Date header:

```
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H

#include "Time.h"

class Date 
{
public:
   static const unsigned int monthsPerYear = 12; // months in a year
   Date( int = 1, int = 1, int = 1900, Time = Time()); // default constructor
   ~Date(); // provided to confirm destruction order
   void print() const; // print date in month/day/year format
   void tick();      // function that increments seconds by 1.
   void increaseADay(); // increases the day by one
private:
   unsigned int month; // 1-12 (January-December)
   unsigned int day;  // 1-31 based on month
   unsigned int year; // any year
   Time time;         // private Time object - class composition
   // utility function to check if day is proper for month and year
   unsigned int checkDay( int ); 
}; // end class Date

#endif
```

Time header:

```
#ifndef TIME_H
#define TIME_H

// Time class definition
class Time 
{
public:
   explicit Time( int = 0, int = 0, int = 0 ); // default constructor
   ~Time();  // destructor
   // set functions
   void setTime( int, int, int ); // set hour, minute, second
   void setHour( int ); // set hour (after validation)
   void setMinute( int ); // set minute (after validation)
   void setSecond( int ); // set second (after validation)

   // get functions
   unsigned int getHour() const; // return hour
   unsigned int getMinute() const; // return minute
   unsigned int getSecond() const; // return second

   void printUniversal() const; // output time in universal-time format
   void printStandard() const; // output time in standard-time format
private:
   unsigned int hour; // 0 - 23 (24-hour clock format)
   unsigned int minute; // 0 - 59
   unsigned int second; // 0 - 59
}; // end class Time

#endif
```

Date class implementation file:

```
// Date class member-function definitions.
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Date.h" // include Date class definition
#include "Time.h" // include the Time class definition
using namespace std;

// constructor confirms proper value for month; calls
// utility function checkDay to confirm proper value for day
Date::Date( int mn, int dy, int yr, Time time)
{
   if ( mn > 0 && mn <= monthsPerYear ) // validate the month
      month = mn;
   else 
      throw invalid_argument( "month must be 1-12" );

   year = yr; // could validate yr
   day = checkDay( dy ); // validate the day
   // output Date object to show when its constructor is called
   cout << "Date object constructor for date ";
   print();                   
   cout << endl;
} // end Date constructor



// print Date object in form month/day/year
void Date::print() const
{
   cout << month << '/' << day << '/' << year; 
   cout << "\t";
   time.printStandard();
   cout << "\t";
   time.printUniversal();
} // end function print

// output Date object to show when its destructor is called
Date::~Date()
{ 
   cout << "Date object destructor for date ";
   print();
   cout << endl;
} // end ~Date destructor

// function to increment Time by one second
void Date::tick()
{
   int tempSecond = time.getSecond();
   if (tempSecond < 59)
   {
      tempSecond++;
      time.setSecond(tempSecond);
   }
   else if (tempSecond >= 59)
   {
      time.setSecond(0);
      int tempMin = time.getMinute();
      if (tempMin < 59)
      {
         tempMin++;
         time.setMinute(tempMin);
      }
      else if (tempMin >= 59)
      {
         time.setMinute(0);
         int tempHour = time.getHour();
         if (tempHour < 23)
         {
            tempHour++;
            time.setHour(tempHour);
         }
         else if (tempHour >= 23)
         {
            time.setHour(0);
            increaseADay();
         }
      }
   }
}

void Date::increaseADay()
{
   checkDay(++day);
}

// utility function to confirm proper day value based on 
// month and year; handles leap years, too
unsigned int Date::checkDay( int testDay )
{
   static const array< int, monthsPerYear + 1 > daysPerMonth = 
      { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

   // determine whether testDay is valid for specified month
   if ( testDay > 0 && testDay <= daysPerMonth[ month ] )
      return testDay;

   // February 29 check for leap year 
   if ( month == 2 && testDay == 29 && ( year % 400 == 0 || 
      ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 ) ) )
      return testDay;
   if (testDay > daysPerMonth[month])
   {
      month++;
      day = 1;
      if (month > monthsPerYear)
      {
         year++;
         month = 1;
         day = 1;
         return 0;
      }
   }

   throw invalid_argument( "Invalid day for current month and year" );
} // end function checkDay
```

Time class implementation file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "Time.h" // include definition of class Time from Time.h
using namespace std;

// Time constructor initializes each data member 
Time::Time( int hour, int minute, int second ) 
{ 
   cout << "Time object constructor is called ";
   setTime( hour, minute, second ); // validate and set time
   cout << "\t";
   printStandard();  // call the print standard function
   cout << "\t";
   printUniversal(); // call the print universal function.
   cout << endl;
} // end Time constructor

// Time destructor - calls printStandard and printUniversal
Time::~Time()
{
   // print a message indicating that we are destructing
   cout << "Time object destructor called.";
   // call printStandard and printUniversal functions
   printStandard();
   printUniversal();
} // end Time destructor

// set new Time value using universal time
void Time::setTime( int h, int m, int s )
{
   setHour( h ); // set private field hour
   setMinute( m ); // set private field minute
   setSecond( s ); // set private field second
} // end function setTime

// set hour value
void Time::setHour( int h )
{
   if ( h >= 0 && h < 24 )  // validate the input
      hour = h;
   else                     // throw an error if hour is not valid.
      throw invalid_argument( "hour must be 0-23" );
} // end function setHour

// set minute value
void Time::setMinute( int m )
{
   if ( m >= 0 && m < 60 )  // validate the input
      minute = m; 
   else                     // throw an error if hour is not valid.
      throw invalid_argument( "minute must be 0-59" );
} // end function setMinute

// set second value
void Time::setSecond( int s )
{
   if ( s >= 0 && s < 60 )
      second = s;
   else
      throw invalid_argument( "second must be 0-59" );
} // end function setSecond

// return hour value
unsigned int Time::getHour() const
{
   return hour;
} // end function getHour

// return minute value
unsigned int Time::getMinute() const
{
   return minute;
} // end function getMinute

// return second value
unsigned int Time::getSecond() const
{
   return second;
} // end function getSecond

// print Time in universal-time format (HH:MM:SS)
void Time::printUniversal() const
{
   // set field widths and fill characters to print format "00:00:00"
   // setfill is sticky, setw is not
   cout << setfill( '0' ) << setw( 2 ) << getHour() << ":"
      << setw( 2 ) << getMinute() << ":" << setw( 2 ) << getSecond();
} // end function printUniversal

// print Time in standard-time format (HH:MM:SS AM or PM)
void Time::printStandard() const
{
   // set field widths and fill characters to print format "00:00:00"
   // use the conditional operator to check if time is equal to 0 or 12
   // if so, mod the hour by 12 to put it in 12 hour clock format.
   cout << ( ( getHour() == 0 || getHour() == 12 ) ? 12 : getHour() % 12 )
      << ":" << setfill( '0' ) << setw( 2 ) << getMinute()
      << ":" << setw( 2 ) << getSecond() << ( hour < 12 ? " AM" : " PM" );
} // end function printStandard
```

If you run this and look at the first two lines of console output, it shows the time constructor printing the set time.  The second print shows how the time constructor is called again setting the data members to 00:00:00.  This is what I'm trying to avoid.  I can't figure out why the Time constructor is being called a second time...

Comment: For starters you're explicitly calling the destructor, which results in undefined behavior when `d` is destroyed again at the end of `main`, so the rest of your question is pretty much moot until you fix this. There's also too much unrelated code, and none of the code that could actually explain your issue. Please rewrite your question with an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If you're referring to the explicit destructor call in the test code, I'm not allowed to change this.  This was code supplied by my teacher and he said my objects must work with this...

Comment: Unless your teacher told you "please don't do this in real code" I would be very suspicious of his C++ teaching ability. The explicit call is not only wrong, it has absolutely no purpose, `d` will already be destroyed before `t`. I see you've stripped the code, but you still haven't provided definitions for your constructors. Please read the mvce link again, you need to post something that can be copied, pasted, and compiled as-is.

Comment: I agree with your suspicious of his C++ teaching ability.  I've already had to correct him in the past when he graded me down on an assignment for using the new C++11 in-class initialization feature for data members.  I also had to correct him when he graded me down for using the recommended Array class template rather than built in C-Style arrays.  Sadly, he is still my teacher and I still must work with what he gives me.  Regarding my code, it would be better if I included everything then, including my two class implementation files.  I can't cut parts out and expect it to compile...

Comment: That's ok, as long as it compiles. I guess the destructor call is there because otherwise `d` won't be destroyed until after `pause` is called to keep the command window open. This is easily solved by either running the app from an open command window, or by introducing a new block scope to force the destruction of `t` and `d` before `pause` is called.

Comment: Those that can do do; those how can't teach

Comment: Ok I included my entire class header and implementation files.  Some comments are still missing with my code.  I tested the tick function which increments the time and date correctly, but I shortened the loop so it only prints 20 times before exiting.  The important thing is the first two console prints - you see the constructor first set the time to the supplied arguments by the test program, then you see it called again setting the data members to the default value 00:00:00...this is the part I can't figure out...

Comment: The answers are correct (you were forgetting to initialize the time sub-object of date). My wild suspect is however that it wasn't that you forgot, but that you didn't know you had to initialize sub-object. This is a very basilar concept of the C++ model (like that you **almost never** have to call destructors explicitly): keeping on piling up C++ code without fixing the basics first is going to be a **very** bad idea. My suggestion is to read now a good C++ book from cover to cover, before it's too late. It's just plain impossible to learn C++ by experimenting, you must read.

Comment: Yes, I am reading a C++ book right now. It seems ok, I just need more time to practice.  I've read 12 chapters so far. But the problem is at the same time, I've also read 10 chapters in a Java book, and 8 chapters in an assembly book. All this while completing the homework for each of these classes, plus my regular classes (calc 3 and Physics). I read, but I don't do the end of chapter activities because I simply don't have time. To compound this, the classes I'm learning C++ and Java in are online, so it's purely up to me to teach myself the material. Hence my sub-par understanding...

Comment: And yes, I did forget. I read about constructor initialization lists. This was my first opportunity to actually use it.  So I did forget. Reading is nice. But you have to actually do it before it truly makes sense.  At least, that's how things have been for me.

Comment: @Sabien: I'm not saying you're lazy. I was just informing you that experimental path with C++ is going to be a disaster, no matter how smart you are (actually, in a sense, the smarter you are and the worse it is). C++ is not a clean "logical" design, but the result of the works of a committee on top of an initial hack. There's no way you can guess what the committee decided, you must read. Also the language assumes that programmers never make errors. C++ is a good powerful tool, but it's complex and illogical so you need to read the instruction first, or you'll cut off both your hands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm looking at your `Date` constructor, and some things strike me:

- It begins by `Date::Date( int mn, int dy, int yr, Time time) {`, without using `:`, meaning that your `Data::time` field will be initialized using `Time`'s default constructor
- You don't use the `time` parameter of your constructor, and in particular you don't assign it to `Data::time`

I guess that explains your problem

Comment: Yes, you are right, I forgot about the constructor initialization list.  Adding this simple line ': time(time)' after the constructor fixed it.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `this->time = time;` in your `Date` constructor. That is what you are missing.